# how to break-word in multiple select with specific width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to wrap the content inside multiple select.

here is the fiddle:
**http://jsfiddle.net/jH5b6/2/**

```
<select id="field9" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1523">Imaging angiogenesis Part 2: Targeting the vasculature in Cancer research</option>
    <option value="1540">Imaging guided investigation in Cancer Drug Development</option>
    <option value="1541">Vascular strain – measuring changes in vessel wall motion</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `wrap`? What isn't working as expected?

Comment: i should able to see the whole text even if we specify width

Comment: Your question is very low quality. But if i'm understood you, you can use optgroup for wrapping of options into one logic block

Comment: If you define width you are restraining the browser from displaying the whole line. The option will not display on more than 1 line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done with `<select>` elements. The browser determines how to render them and the option elements inside.

The option elements in a multiple select only take up one line.

Instead, you could use a plugin or a library select tool, or create one of your own with JS/CSS.

Comment: actually I had a form which has some width. the select with multiple takes the width of the parent and some of text gets hidden

Comment: @susheel I don't understand. Are you asking me something or telling me something?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want since html form controls are very limited in what they can do.
You need to use a plugin ([Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)) in order to achieve that.

PS. You can also create your own plugin to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can not wrap the text inside your listbox control. However you can set width to "0px". In this way, ListBox will automatically adjust its width to maximum width of your content.

```
 asp:listbox id="lstItems" runat="server" Width="0px" Height="0px" style="color:White; border:0px; border-color:White" SelectionMode="Multiple" /asp:listbox
```

Comment: can you give a fiddle example using plain html instead of asp

Comment: Long back I had the same problem and fortunately I was on .net framework so I solved that problem by setting width to 0px. I am not sure about plain HTML. Wish I cud help.